# Date comparison program

Tags: c

Can anyone spot what's wrong with my code?
It should simply compare Dates and the earliest one should get recorded, however only my first input is. Walked through it slowly can't see where my logic error is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int month=1, day=1, year=1;
   int fmonth=0, fday=0, fyear=0;

   while((month != 0) && (day != 0) && (year != 0))
   {
      printf("Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel) ");
      scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);
      if(fyear < year)
      {
         fyear = year;
         fmonth = month;
         fday = day;
      }
      else if ((fyear == year) && (fmonth < month) && (fday <= day))
      {
         fyear=year;
         fmonth=month;
         fday=day;
      }
   }

   printf("Earliest Date is: %d/%d/%d\n", fmonth,fday,fyear);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Among other issues, take a look at the code `(fmonth < month) && (fday <= day)`. Is this handling the case correctly where the new month is earlier, but the new day is later? What about the case where the new month is the same but the new day is later?

Comment: Also what should the initial values for fmonth, fday, fyear be? If they start as 0, what sort of new dates would be considered earlier than that?

Comment: You need to consider `fyear < year`, and then `fyear == year && fmonth < month`, and then `fyear == year && fmonth == month && fday < day` conditions.  And then you need to fix things so that you look for the smallest value, not the biggest value as you currently do.  That probably means starting with `fmonth` et al initialized to `INT_MAX` rather than `0`.

Comment: Hey Johnathan! You're right I've fixed the comparison errors however the initial zero values that have to be placed to close the loop are messing with me! Could you please explain INT_MAX? Can't find anything online

Comment: `INT_MAX` is the maximum possible integer value, a value defined in `<limits.h>`.  Either I've got Google trained or you aren't using it — I simply type `int_max` into the search box and it comes up [trumps](https://www.quora.com/What-is-INT_MIN-and-INT_MAX-in-C++) (or [trumps](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)) for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hah, this was kinda fun. Your primary problem was you had your comparisons turned around backwards. (and you needed to add a `(month == fmonth)` test) Your secondary problem was a total failure to **validate user input** -- it will bite you every time.

First, you want to check if `(date < fdate)` before assigning, not if `(fdate < date)` or you will overwrite your earlier date with a later one (as yuchaun correctly noted originally).

Always, **always**, *validate user input*. For all you know a cat may be stepping on the keyboard. At minimum, at least check the return of `scanf` to validate that the number of conversions to `int` you expected, did in fact take place (validating the values fall into valid *month, day, year* ranges is left to you).

Putting those pieces together, and replacing the `"0/0/0"` cancellation with a simple counter to determine when you have two dates entered, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int month = 1, day = 1, year = 1,
        fmonth = 0, fday = 0, fyear = 0,
        n = 0;  /* simple counter - no need for 0/0/0 */

    while (1) { /* just loop until you have 2 dates */
        printf ("Enter the date: ");

        /* validate ALL User Input */
        if (scanf ("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year) != 3) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid date, exiting.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        /* if no fdate or if (date < fdate) then fdate = date */
        if (!n || (year < fyear) || 
            ((year == fyear) && ((month < fmonth) || 
            ((month == fmonth) && (day < fday))))) {
            fyear = year;
            fmonth = month;
            fday = day;
        }
        if (++n == 2)   /* increment counter and test */
            break;
    }

    printf ("Earliest Date : %d/%d/%d\n", fmonth, fday, fyear);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/earlierdate
Enter the date: 12/21/1991
Enter the date: 12/22/1991
Earliest Date : 12/21/1991

$ ./bin/earlierdate
Enter the date: 12/22/1991
Enter the date: 12/21/1991
Earliest Date : 12/21/1991
```

When you run into a problem like this, always see [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and don't be shy about talking to the duck... it works!

Look things over, and consider all answers, and let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Some errors in your code include:

1. `if (fyear < year)`: Say previously I got `fyear =  2015`, now I scan `year = 2012`. Is `2015 < 2012` ? So, the conditions will be `reversed`, right?
2. Now the problem with reversing is, `fmonth=0, fday=0, fyear=0`. Suppose, I scan year = 2012. So, check `(fyear > year)` ⇒ `(0 > 2012)`? It won't be updated. So, change the `initialization`.
3. Lastly, if you scan 0/0/0, and say our present `fyear = 2012` and `year = 0`. So, `fyear > year` ⇒ `2012 > 0`, this updates the whole thing to 0/0/0. We need to take care the `when to scan` because while loop executes the whole thing before checking the previous scan.
4. `(fyear == year) && (fmonth < month) && (fday <= day)` What if only present month is less than the previous? The conditions should be `||`

So, I think you can draw a solution like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(void)
{

  int fmonth=INT_MAX, fday=INT_MAX, fyear=INT_MAX, month=INT_MAX, year = INT_MAX, day = INT_MAX;

  while(month != 0 && year != 0 && day != 0)
  {
   if(year<fyear || (year==fyear && month<fmonth) || (year==fyear && month==fmonth && day<fday))
    {
      fyear = year;
      fmonth = month;
      fday = day;
    }
    printf("Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel) ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);
  }
  printf("Earliest Date is: %d/%d/%d\n", fmonth,fday,fyear);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I enter `12/11/2010` and `11/12/2014`, your code reports that `11/12/2014` is the earliest date because the month is smaller.  You need to revisit the condition testing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, can you please tell me if I'm correct now?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I'm sorry! I actually overlooked that condition. Thanks for rectifying me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the decision tree is hard to debug and write, you should first ensure that all months and days are within a proper range.
Then it's just a matter of assigning a proper weight to each *digit* in this possibly mixed radix number system:

```
 int days_total = w_y * years + w_m * months + w_d * days;
```

And same for the other date. The comparison reduces to comparing this linearized date with any w_d >= 1, w_m >= 31, w_y >= 366.

Suggested values are 1,32 and 512 for best performance.

Comment: Using w_d = 1, w_m = 100, w_y = 10000 is also quite convenient.

Comment: Absolutely, 100 is good candidate for fixed radix making the linearized value also human readable eg 20170730.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually overwriting the value of fyear,fmonth,fdays when the date entered is LATER than the stored fyear/month/day, which I don't think is your intention

I get the following output:

```
$ ./a.out
Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel) 1/2/3
Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel) 3/4/5
Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel) 0/0/0
Earliest Date is: 3/4/5
$ ./a.out
Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel) 3/4/5
Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel) 1/2/3
Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel) 0/0/0
Earliest Date is: 3/4/5
$ ./a.out
Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel) 1/2/3
Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel) 0/0/0
Earliest Date is: 1/2/3
```

so it's not just the first input that's being captured, but the date recorded is the latest, not the earliest.

Comment: Thank you yuchuan!
However I still don't understand if my final year is less than my initial year wouldn't I wish to overwrite it then?

Comment: NVM I totally caught it while I was talking it out loud, thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You made a little mistake when comparing in

```
if(fyear < year)
```

Since you save the user input in variable `year`, you only record the date which is the latest, not the earliest.

But simply changing the operator won't work here, you need to implement this program anew. Try imaging how the comparison works best.

Tips:

- Maybe try using ranges for days and month (1 <= day <= 28, 30, 31 and 1 <= month <= 12)
- Your idea to compare first the year in your second if-statement was okay, now try the same for month and day like this:

  ```
  if(year <= fyear) {
      if(month <= fmonth) {
          if(day <= day) {
              fday = day;
              fmonth = month;
              fyear = year;
          }else{
              /* nothing happens, since date 
               * is later than the current */
          }
      }else{
          // your logic here
      }
  }else{
      // your logic here
  }
  ```
- Maybe assign the values to the fyear, fmonth and fday variables immediately when they are all 0. Because when comparing to input dates, an if-statement which checks wether the input date is earlier than the initial (0/0/0) date will always fail.

Comment: That's a very bushy decision tree, and hard to keep track of.

Comment: The code from **JohnnyJedial** can't be fixed by applying minimal changes. Of course this is why I wrote he should try to implement this in another way. I merely tried to give him a hint by extending his own code.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I edited your code and included some statements to make the program user friendly. I think this will ensure your requirement. And also you have to consider, Feb 29(leap year) month,year date > 0.

```
   #include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

   int month=1, day=1, year=1;
   int fmonth, fday, fyear;

   printf("Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel)\n ");
   scanf("%d/%d/%d", &fday, &fmonth, &fyear);
   while(1)
   {

   printf("1.Do you want to continue.\n2.print the result.\n");
   int ch;
   scanf("%d",&ch);
   if(ch==2){break;}

   printf("Enter the date: (0/0/0 to cancel)\n ");
   scanf("%d/%d/%d", &day, &month, &year);
   if(fyear > year)
   {
       fyear = year;
       fmonth = month;
       fday = day;
   }
  else if ((fyear == year) && (fmonth > month))
   {
       fyear=year;
       fmonth=month;
       fday=day;
   }
   else
   {if ((fyear == year) && (fmonth == month) && (fday > day))
   {
       fyear=year;
       fmonth=month;
       fday=day;
   }
   }
}


 printf("Earliest Date is: %d/%d/%d\n",fday,fmonth,fyear);





    return 0;
}
```